# weird error with asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am getting a very strange client side javascript error when using asp.net ajax tool kit.

I am using user controls with a timer inside of an update panel to make call backs to the server
the error is Type Sys.UI._Timer has already been registered

I can't recreate the issue at all when debugging the site localy or if the site is published on my machine, The error only happens when the site is published to our QA machine and only happens in IE and only happens on 2 out of the 6 machines we have used to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of javascript caching? Tried clearing the browser cache? If you have IE8 then hit F12 and use the debugger - might help.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you're loading the same script twice